# Diazo + Apache + mod_transform: theming `/` different from other paths

Tags: apache, themes, diazo

I'm using [Diazo](http://diazo.org/) (formerly XDV) to theme some internal websites, using Apache and [mod_transform_html](https://launchpad.net/mod-transform).  I was hoping I could make use of multiple distinct themes by putting `TransformSet` directives inside `Location` directives, like this:

```
<Location /blog/>
   TransformSet /themes/blog.xsl
</Location>

<Location />
   TransformSet /themes/main.xsl
</Location>
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the `TransformSet` directive for `/` always takes precedence.  I've solved this for the time being by moving content from `/` to `/main` and adding:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /main/ [R]

<Location /main/>
   TransformSet /themes/main.xsl
</Location>
```

This works, but I would rather be able to host this content rooted at `/`.

So...is there a way to override a transformation applied to `/`?  This sort of thing seems to work for other Apache configuration directives (e.g., `ProxyPass`).

Comment: I kind of wonder what inspired the today's -1 vote on this 10-year-old question. I would be happy to improve it, although it's been about 10 years since I was working with this technology :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got around to finishing the paramater support for mod_transform, but if you can choose between themes based on page content, then you could use something like:

```
<rules css:if-content="#blog">
  <theme href="blog.html"/>
  ...
</rules>
<rules if="not(//*[@id='blog']">
  <theme href="main.html"/>
  ...
</rules>
```

This reminds me I should add an if-not-content so you can use a css selector there. For more, see: http://diazo.org/advanced.html#multiple-conditional-themes

It might be easier though just to use LocationMatch instead for the root theme, something like:

```
<LocationMatch "/(?!blog)">
   TransformSet /themes/main.xsl
</LocationMatch>
```

That would avoid both TransformSet directives applying to the same request.

Comment: I had actually experimented with the `if-content` directive, but it looked like things were going to end up getting messy.  It would be a lot more manageable to keep the transforms in separate files.  I'll try out the `LocationMatch` solution.

Comment: The conditions seem to work fairly well for closely related themes that share many of their rules, e.g. a standard page and a front page. With completely unrelated pages it does get messy. Deliverance attempted to solve this with 'page classes' (http://packages.python.org/Deliverance/configuration.html#match-and-page-classes) and perhaps we need something similar for Diazo, along with something that translates to an <xsl:choose>.

Comment: Is the fact that `TransformSet` on a subpath won't override the setting for `/` a general Apache thing?  Or could this be fixed in `mod_transform`?

Comment: I guess it could be fixed in mod_transform (perhaps by defining the directive in a different way.) I'd certainly take a look at a patch for this.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct or not but [this patch](https://gist.github.com/1323250) modifies the behavior such that `TransformSet` on a subordinate path will take precedence over one set on a higher level path.